# Verifying Simple Expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an expression for $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x$ and $y$ are of opposite signs (and $x,y \ne 0$). So, I let $x=m$ and $y=-n$ for $m,n \in \mathbb{R}$, and my expression is:

\begin{align*}
& 2(m)(-n)-(m)^2(-n)^4+3(m)^3(-n)\\
= {} & -n[2m-m^2(-n)^3+3m^3]\\
= {} & -n[2m+m^2n^3+3m^3]
\end{align*}

Now - the part that I'm not sure about:

Can I simply say the expression in the brackets is positive? I believe it is, because I've accounted for all of the negatives in my work, and they've cancelled out/been factored out with the $-n$.

So, then I could say the expression is less than $0$ since it is a negative number $\times$ a positive number.

It just seems like somehow I should be showing in another way that the expression in the brackets is positive?

*Edit to add - I would like to show that the expression above is less than 0. I see now that I need to prove the signs of my variables and would appreciate help with that*

Sticking with m and n as variables (to make copy/paste easier and quicker) I'll rewrite with some advice from the comments:

$m,n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $m,n \ne 0$ and $m$ and $n$ are opposite signs. I want to show $2(m)(n)-(m)^2(n)^4+3(m)^3(n)< 0$.

Let $m>0$,and $n<0$ then
\begin{align*}
& 2(m)(n)-(m)^2(n)^4+3(m)^3(n)\\
= {} & n[2m-m^2(n)^3+3m^3] \quad \textrm{Since } n<0, n^3<0\\
= {} & n[2m+m^2n^3+3m^3]
\end{align*}

So now, I've established their signs at the (new) beginning, but I have the same problem of having an n in the brackets. Does the fact that it's $-ve$ cancel out with the $-ve$ in front of the $m$ make it a positive?

Comment: So far you don't know that $m \gt 0, n \gt 0$. Your substitution only guarantees that $ m \cdot n = -x \cdot y \gt 0$.

Comment: @dxiv - So, it's not enough to just state that x and y are opposite signs by assigning them values such that x is $+m$ and y is $-n$...I guess if n was negative, then $-n$ would be positive, which is where this becomes a problem?

Comment: Right. The substitution only moved from $x,y$ of opposite signs to $m,n$ of the same sign, but it doesn't establish which sign that may be.

Comment: Would it be enough to simply state $m,n >0$ before my calculations, or is this something that would need to be shown later on?

Comment: Or, I guess I could say $x=m$, and $y=-m$ for some real number $m$...but x doesn't necessarily equal y either.

Comment: You can't *state* that, you would need to *prove* it. Maybe you can otherwise determine that $x \gt 0$, then that would be sufficient, but you haven't shown the full context to the question.

Comment: I'll edit that in, I'm just showing, in general, that it's less than 0. I see that I didn't state it clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $-n(2m+m^2n^3+3m^3) = -m n \big(2 + (m n)n^2 + 3 m^2\big) \lt 0$ given $mn \gt 0$.

Comment: I've rewritten it so that m and n are my main variables (easier to copy and paste the edit) and simply let one of the variables (m) be >0, and n<0. I have an answer that is very similar to my original, except I'm still left with the fact that I have an n in the brackets. I've accounted for the n being negative so I know that it's positive in the brackets, I'm just not sure it's showing that way (if what I know is coming across on the page)

Comment: I had the inequality reversed in the answer, fixed now. Note that it refers to your original question, not the edited one. It relies on just $m n \gt 0, n^2 \gt 0, m^2 \gt 0$, without assumptions on the signs of $m,n$ each.